# Instead of index.php file localhost displaying apache default page

Tags: wordpress, apache, wordpress-theming

I am using XUbuntu. I installed WordPress on localhost. Instead of index.php my homepage displays apache default page. I thought it has something to do with the permissions. But even after changing folder permissions. I am not able to see index.php

Comment: are you accessing folder or just clicking on main root?

Comment: Do share image and path you are accessing for better understanding